# AngularJS: Unix timestamps, Ng-Models and HTML date inputs

Tags: angularjs, date, model, timestamp

When working with an input of 'date' type, what is the best way to take a Unix timestamp from a json feed and format it correctly using AngularJS and ng-models?

Using this markup:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="item.date" />
```

doesn't work as the input expects either a date or string in a particular format rather than a timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

```
item.date = new Date(timestamp)
```

Comment: you should flesh out your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could create directive for all inputs, for example:

```
angular.directive("input", function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, modelCtrl) {
            if (attr['type'] === 'date') {
                modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                    if (modelValue) {
                        return new Date(modelValue);
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```